# Как при помощи консоли получить список строк из .log файла

Tags: ubuntu, shell

Интересует вопрос. Есть log файл с определенными ключами. Как получить список строк:

1. Количество уникальных IP-адресов, упомянутых в этом файле
2. Количество строк с пометкой [report] для символа евро-доллар (ls=EUR/USD)
3. Среднее время исполнения этих сделок из пункта 2. (время исполнения сделки в секундах содержится в поле et=)

Кусок лога:

```
2016-04-05 14:08:28.433880 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137419252=20160405-12:08:28.43356=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_87268=1279=0269=1278=7255=USD/RUB270=69.0012215=USD271=500000346=110=058
2016-04-05 14:08:28.434880 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137419352=20160405-12:08:28.43556=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_52268=1279=0269=1278=1055=AUD/USD270=0.7535115=AUD271=3000000346=110=011
2016-04-05 14:08:28.499887 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=22435=X49=CNX34=2137419452=20160405-12:08:28.50056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_62268=2279=0269=0278=2555=EUR/JPY270=125.77215=EUR271=2000000346=2279=0269=1278=2655=EUR/JPY270=125.77515=EUR271=1000000346=110=087
2016-04-05 14:08:28.499887 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137419552=20160405-12:08:28.50056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_62268=1279=0269=0278=2555=EUR/JPY270=125.77215=EUR271=1500000346=110=061
2016-04-05 14:08:28.519889 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15635=X49=CNX34=2137419652=20160405-12:08:28.52056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_72268=1279=0269=0278=4155=GBP/NZD270=2.094515=GBP271=2000000346=210=218
2016-04-05 14:08:28.519889 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15635=X49=CNX34=2137419752=20160405-12:08:28.52056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_72268=1279=0269=0278=4155=GBP/NZD270=2.094515=GBP271=1500000346=110=222
2016-04-05 14:08:28.554892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137419852=20160405-12:08:28.55556=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_68268=1279=0269=0278=3355=GBP/AUD270=1.8829315=GBP271=3000000346=210=021
2016-04-05 14:08:28.554892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137419952=20160405-12:08:28.55556=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_69268=1279=0269=0278=3555=GBP/CAD270=1.8689715=GBP271=1000000346=110=012
2016-04-05 14:08:28.554892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=22435=X49=CNX34=2137420052=20160405-12:08:28.55556=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_68268=2279=0269=0278=3355=GBP/AUD270=1.8829315=GBP271=2000000346=1279=0269=1278=3455=GBP/AUD270=1.8831715=GBP271=1000000346=110=226
2016-04-05 14:08:28.554892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137420152=20160405-12:08:28.55556=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_74268=1279=0269=1278=4655=GBP/USD270=1.4188815=GBP271=1500000346=110=027
2016-04-05 14:08:28.555892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137420252=20160405-12:08:28.55656=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_70268=1279=0269=1278=3855=GBP/CHF270=1.3597615=GBP271=3000000346=110=253
2016-04-05 14:08:28.555892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137420352=20160405-12:08:28.55756=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_71268=1279=0269=1278=4055=GBP/JPY270=157.00115=GBP271=2000000346=110=009
2016-04-05 14:08:28.567894 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15635=X49=CNX34=2137420452=20160405-12:08:28.56856=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_63268=1279=0269=1278=2855=EUR/NZD270=1.6782715=EUR271=500000346=110=021
2016-04-05 14:08:28.569892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15735=X49=CNX34=2137420552=20160405-12:08:28.57056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_78268=1279=0269=0278=5355=NZD/USD270=0.6773415=NZD271=1000000346=110=059
2016-04-05 14:08:28.569892 0x000009e4 [trace] FIX CURRENEX [in] 8=FIX.4.29=15635=X49=CNX34=2137420652=20160405-12:08:28.57056=XXXXstr262=XXXXXX_51268=1279=0269=0278=755=AUD/NZD270=1.1123115=AUD271=3000000346=210=206
```

Comment: Добавил, фрагмент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

примерно так:

> Количество уникальных IP-адресов, упомянутых в этом файле

```
$ grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b' test.log | sort -u | wc -l
```

> Количество строк с пометкой [report] для символа евро-доллар (ls=EUR/USD)

```
$ grep '\[report\]' test.log | grep 'ls=EUR/USD' | wc -l
```

> Среднее время исполнения этих сделок из пункта 2. (время исполнения сделки в секундах содержится в поле et=)

тут требуется уточнение — что такое «сделки» вообще и «эти из пункта 2» — в частности.

если «сделки» — это опечатка, и подразумевалось слово «строки» (из пункта 2), то количество строк уже подсчитано в пункте 2, а сумму чисел после `et=` можно подсчитать, например, так:

```
$ grep '\[report\]' test.log | grep 'ls=EUR/USD' | \
 sed -r 's/.*et=([0-9.]+)\b.*/+\1/;1s/^/scale=5;0/' | xargs echo | bc
```

а после этого просто разделить `сумму` на `количество`:

```
$ echo 'scale=5; сумма/количество' | bc
```

получится арифметическое среднее.

Comment: Спасибо. Со всем разобрался, всё работает.